# CesiumJS animate movement from position to other position

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have `from` coordinates and `to` coordinates (latitude and longitude)
I draw line between this 2 coordinates with plane 3d model:

```
this.viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
   shouldAnimate: true,
   terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain()
});

const position = [36.778259, -119.417931, 31, 35];
const m = await Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(362867); // This is just an ID of my 3D model

const modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
     Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(36.778259, -119.417931, 5000.0)
);
const model = this.viewer.scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
     url : m,
     modelMatrix,
     clampToGround: false,
     scale : 30000.0
}));

this.viewer.entities.add({
    name: 'Red line on terrain',
    polyline: {
         positions: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(position),
         width: 5,
         material: Cesium.Color.RED,
         clampToGround: true
     },
     position,
     orientation: new Cesium.VelocityOrientationProperty(position),
     model,
     path: {
        resolution: 1,
        material: new Cesium.PolylineGlowMaterialProperty({
           glowPower: 0.1,
           color: Cesium.Color.YELLOW
        }),
      width: 10
   }
});
```

Is there simple way to animate this model from position (36.778259, -119.417931) to position (31, 35) without calculating each step of latitude and longitude on this line?
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you seen the [Interpolation Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Interpolation.html)?  Is that close to what you're asking for?

Comment: (Use the combo box at the top to switch the interpolation from "Linear" to "Lagrange" to get a much smoother ride).